# Applying arithmetic functions to elements of sublists where the first element of each sublist is the same

Tags: python, text-processing, sublist

Here is my problem.

I have a list of lists, as follows:

```
linesort=[
  ['Me', 1, 596], 
  ['Mine', 1, 551], 
  ['Myself', 1, 533], 
  ['Myself', 1, 624], 
  ['Myself', 1, 656], 
  ['Myself', 1, 928], 
  ['Theirs', 1, 720], 
  ['Theirs', 1, 1921], 
  ['Them', 1, 716], 
  ['Themselves', 1, 527]
]
```

Each of the sublists represents the time taken by  participant to classify the word, either correctly or incorrectly (the second value) and the time to response (the third value).
What I would like to do is return another list of lists, which has the word, the sum of the second values in each list, and the average of the third values.

Essentially, I need to compare the first element of each sublist, and if they are equal, then compute the sum of the second element and the average of the third element.

While i was able to do this by hand (i.e. manually assigning and creating variables) my attempts to do so in a loop have all failed. Given that I have two quite large text files with this kind of data, i would appreciate a programmatic solution.

Some points which may be useful: I know in advance what words are used in each test, but I do not know where they will appear (and even if they appear in any one group of stimuli). 
Can anyone help me out with this?

I am using Python 2.6.5 on Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the beautiful one but:

```
from collections import defaultdict

linesort = [['Me', 1, 596], ['Mine', 1, 551], ['Myself', 1, 533], ['Myself', 1, 624],
            ['Myself', 1, 656], ['Myself', 1, 928], ['Theirs', 1, 720], 
            ['Theirs', 1, 1921], ['Them', 1, 716], ['Themselves', 1, 527]]

d = defaultdict(list)
for line in linesort:
    d[line[0]].append(line[1:])


output = {}
for x,val in d.items():
    svals = [y[1] for y in val]
    output[x] = [sum([y[0] for y in val]), sum(svals) / len(svals)] # need to be modified if you need float value

print output
>>> {'Mine': [1, 551], 'Theirs': [2, 1320], 'Me': [1, 596], 'Them': [1, 716], 'Themselves': [1, 527], 'Myself': [4, 685]}
```

Or using groupby(note that it is not the most efficient and require list with initial data to be sorted):

```
from itertools import groupby

res = {}
for key, gen in groupby(sorted(linesort), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    val = list(gen)
    svals = [y[2] for y in val]
    res[key] = [sum([y[1] for y in val]), sum(svals) / float(len(svals))]
```

But all my previous samples return you a dictionary so if you want to get a list than you simply need to modify code a bit:

```
from itertools import groupby

res = []
for key, gen in groupby(sorted(linesort), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    val = list(gen)
    svals = [y[2] for y in val]
    res.append([key, sum([y[1] for y in val]), sum(svals) / float(len(svals))])

print res
>>> [['Me', 1, 596.0], ['Mine', 1, 551.0], ['Myself', 4, 685.25], ['Theirs', 2, 1320.5], ['Them', 1, 716.0], ['Themselves', 1, 527.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

My *verbose* solution

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import collections

linesort=[['Me', 1, 596], ['Mine', 1, 551], ['Myself', 1, 533], ['Myself', 1, 624],
          ['Myself', 1, 656], ['Myself', 1, 928],['Theirs', 1, 720], ['Theirs', 1, 1921],
          ['Them', 1, 716], ['Themselves', 1, 527]]
new=[]

d=collections.defaultdict(list)
for i in linesort:
    d[i[0]].append(i[1:])

for k,v in d.iteritems():
    s=sum([i[0] for i in v])
    avg=sum([i[1] for i in v]) / len(v)

    new.append([k,s,avg])

for i in new: print i
```

Output:

```
['Me', 1, 596]
['Myself', 4, 685]
['Theirs', 2, 1320]
['Mine', 1, 551]
['Themselves', 1, 527]
['Them', 1, 716]
```

Comment: again thanks for your answer, it helped me in grasping a little more of Python and its idioms.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my simple solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

linesort=[['Me', 1, 596], ['Mine', 1, 551], ['Myself', 1, 533], ['Myself', 1, 624], ['Myself', 1, 656], ['Myself', 1, 928], ['Theirs', 1, 720], ['Theirs', 1, 1921], ['Them', 1, 716], ['Themselves', 1, 527]]

cnts = {};
sums = {};
# here we count occurrences of each word (cnts),
# and we compute the the sum of second elements of each input list
for list in linesort:
  cnts[list[0]] = cnts.get(list[0], 0) + 1;
  sums[list[0]] = sums.get(list[0], 0) + list[1];

# now that we know the occurrences for each work we can compute
# the averages of the third elements of each input list 
avgs = {};
for list in linesort:
  avgs[list[0]] = avgs.get(list[0], 0) + list[2] / cnts[list[0]];

# we build the result as a list of lists
result = [];
for word in avgs:
  result.append([word, sums[word], avgs[word]]);

print result;
```

And the output is:

```
[['Me', 1, 596], ['Myself', 4, 685], ['Theirs', 2, 1320], ['Mine', 1, 551], ['Themselves', 1, 527], ['Them', 1, 716]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was very clear. I've accepted another answer but nonetheless thank you for your assistance.